# How to configure CloudWatch Rules to auto-delete after specific time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-java-sdk, aws-event-bridge

How to configure CloudWatch Rules to auto-delete after specific time?

I want to create CloudWatch Rules in such a way that they get auto deleted after a fixed time, lets say 2 days (similar to Time To Live concept for Database Items). The problem I'm looking to fix is that there is a max limit of 300 EventBridge Rules per Event bus in a AWS Account. If this limit is reached, it won't create any new CloudWatch Rule.

Comment: You can make a separate bus and create a scheduled event that fires on that bus, then make the event trigger a lambda, then make the lambda do whatever you want via API calls--including deleting events.

Comment: Is that the only way possible? If the Lambda somehow fails processing, the limit can be reached